# rake db:migrate fails - Rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

When I am doing `rake db:migrate` I am getting the below error.

> rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmi

I checked an answer where It is said that there's some path set for rails admin in the `routes` file, I need to remove the same from it.

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

This is part of my route file. Even If I am removing this line, I am getting the same error.

In another answer It said to upgrade rails, I did that as well, but it gives same error.

Please help.

Comment: Have you misspelt `RailsAdmin` somewhere in your app? Try checking the whole stacktrace or searching your app with grep.

Comment: I don't think so as the same code sits on heroku and is working perfectly

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: here it is @max http://pastebin.com/2hhZjEG0